# How to match regular expression on a column for PostgreSQL in EF Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a class called `Cars` with a property called `Index` as string.

The `Index` has a string format of `#0001`, which starts with `#` & is followed by 4 numbers.

When I use SQL Server with EF 5, I get a list of `Index`s of the car using the code below:

```
indexes = myContext.Cars.Where(
    c => EF.Functions.Like(c.Index, "[#][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"));
```

Now, I have migrated to PostgreSQL & use Npgsql EF Core library. The code above does not work anymore.

I have tried using the code below to get the matching `Index`:

```
indexes = myContext.Cars
                    .Where(c => EF.Functions.ILike(mp.Index, "#%"));
```

The result above only gives me any string which starts with `#`, but I cannot filter by the matching number of digits.

I also have tried `#[0-9]{4}` expression, but I got no result when it should.

What is the correct expression to use to get the same behaviour in Postgres?

Thanks

Comment: I am confused do you want a solution is SQL Server or Postgres.? They are completely different products.

Comment: @Belayer, I want a solution in Postgres

Comment: Npgsql supports translation to the SQL `Regex.IsMatch`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, can you add your answer how to use `Regex.IsMatch` please?

Comment: Note that LIKE on SQL Server (or PostgreSQL) doesn't support regular expressions, it just happens to work with the subset you need above.

Answer (score 4):

Npgsql EF Core provider supports translation of `Regex.IsMatch` and you can replace `EF.Functions.Like` with this static method:

```cs
indexes = myContext.Cars.Where(
    c => Regex.IsMatch(c.Index, "[#][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"));
```

Full list of functions is here: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/translations.html